# When is personal tragedy an excuse to be immoral?

Tags: ethics

When is personal tragedy an excuse to be immoral? I think my mistake was not being able to see that certain people cannot be moral, due to their own issues.

goodbye

Comment: People are immoral for all sorts of reasons. Whether any of those reasons count as excuses will depend largely upon how you view human nature, and the extent to which you believe agents are morally responsible for their behaviour.  At one extreme, you have people who believe in some sort of libertarian free will. At the other, there are those who do not believe in free will at all. A summary of these views can be found at [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freewill/).

Comment: are people really that self obsessed @Futilitarian

Answer (score 1):

There are many different stances on ethics to evaluate this by. Kant would say there are no excuses, he said you shouldn't even lie to save a life, in [On a Supposed Right to Tell Lies from Benevolent Motives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_a_Supposed_Right_to_Tell_Lies_from_Benevolent_Motives).

We are not robots though. We may feel incapable of doing what we ought to do, or feel incapable of holding back. A great deal of the brain development as teenagers and which only finishes about age 25 relates to impulse control, and in myriad ways in courts and society we recognise the difference. We think traumatic experiences can impair normal healthy development of impulse control. That doesn't mean facing no legal or social results of actions, but it can mean therapy and counselling might do more to prevent a recurrence than a prison sentence. I like the phrase 'Forgiveness doesn't mean no consequences', in regard to recognises people acting under the influence of trauma.

It's interesting to note the emerging link between head injuries and violent crime, thought to be relate to such injuries damaging impulse control. 60 per cent of young adult offenders convicred of violent crime report having suffered brain injuries, between three and six times as many as in the population at large. See eg [Finding links between brain injury and social violence](https://www.exeter.ac.uk/research/ref2014/impact/lifesciences/braininjury/) or [Traumatic brain injury: a potential cause of violent crime?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6171742/) This does not currently impact what sentences people get, but surely you can see an argument that it should.

It sounds like you have a personal axe to grind against someone. And what you are really asking for is permission to not forgive someone who's had a tough time. A wild animal can't be moral, but you can still be compassionate and kind towards it, and not respond to it's hostility with the same. You can take steps to not rely on someone else to behave within certain bounds, but still support them.

Comment: that makes sense. i think the question was a little bitter (and crazy)